# C# Regex Find Phrase in HTML exclude specific tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have HTML text and I have a specific phrase. I need to find my phrase inside HTML text and highlight it, but I have to skip my phrase if it's inside **h** or **a** tags

For Example:
Here is my phrase: "phrase to highlight"

This is my HTML Text

```
<p>Here starts text and here is phrase to highlight</p>
<a>here, phrase to highlight, supposed to be skipped</a>
<h3>here, phrase to highlight, supposed to be skipped</h3>
<div class="phrase to highlight">Here phrase to highlight must be highlighted again</div>
```

p and div tags should highlight my phrase, a and any h tags should skip my phrase.

I do negative lookbehinds to find my phrase and make sure it's not an HTML attribute

```
var Pattern = $"(?i)(?<!</?[^>]*|&[^;]*)(\bphrase to highlight\b)";
```

How can I modify my regex to exclude a and h tags?

Comment: What if it's inside both `p` and `h3`? Does just the closest tag matter? This regex works with your test cases at least: `<(p|div)[\w\s="]*>[^<>]*phrase to highlight`. Anyway, regex is usually not the right tool to parse html, unless maybe you are certain it's very simple.

Comment: Oh, please ... use regex and have two problems ...

Comment: @Andrew unfortunately your solution will not work for me. p and div tags were just examples. it can be any HTML tag, on even without HTML tag

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/982149 ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no nested `a` and `h` tags, use

```
(?<!</?[^>]*|&[^;]*|<(?:a|h\d)(?:\s[^>]*)?>[^<]*)(\bphrase to highlight\b)
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%2F%3F%5B%5E%3E%5D*%7C%26%5B%5E%3B%5D*%7C%3C%28%3F%3Aa%7Ch%5Cd%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%3F%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*%29%28%5Cbphrase%20to%20highlight%5Cb%29&i=%3Cp%3EHere%20starts%20text%20and%20here%20is%20phrase%20to%20highlight%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Ca%3Ehere%2C%20phrase%20to%20highlight%2C%20supposed%20to%20be%20skipped%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%3Ch3%3Ehere%2C%20phrase%20to%20highlight%2C%20supposed%20to%20be%20skipped%3C%2Fh3%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22phrase%20to%20highlight%22%3EHere%20phrase%20to%20highlight%20must%20be%20highlighted%20again%3C%2Fdiv%3E).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    &                        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^;]*                    any character except: ';' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      h                        'h'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    phrase to                'phrase to highlight'
    highlight
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for